# QFontMetrics returning bounding rectangle with very wrong width

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

I'm currently rendering a simple `QGraphicsItem`.  To improve rendering performance, the bounding boxes of it's few internal components are calculated in the constructor.

However I'm having real problems with the text width, as shown by this image:

[image: Bad Rectangles]

I've rendered the calculated BBs with a green line so you can easily see what's happening.  Now I know the `QFontMetrics::boundingRect(..)` isn't perfectly precise as it doesn't take into account italics or font antialising - but that's never more than a few pixels out.

Here's how I calculate the uppermost 'clock' bounding rectangle:

```
QFont font = Sy_application::font();
font.setPointSize( font.pointSize() * 2 );
QFontMetrics fontMet( font );
BB_ = fontMet.boundingRect( getNode()->getName() );
BB_.moveTop( 0.0 );
```

And here is how I use it to render the text in `QGraphicsItem::paint(..)`:

```
QFont font = Sy_application::font();
font.setPointSize( font.pointSize() * 2 );
painter->setFont( font );
painter->setPen( Qt::black );
painter->drawText( BB_.bottomLeft(), getNode()->getName() );
```

I've checked some debug output and `BB_` does not change between being created and used.  In fact the `fontMet.boundingRect( getNode()->getName() );` that creates it, returns a bounding rectangle 45 units wide - the clock icon is 46.  So it is definitely made wrong.

Can anyone see how I am using `QFontMetrics::boundingRect(..)` wrong?

Comment: Does the `boundingRect` calculation return the same thing in the paint   method as it does in the constructor?

Comment: @Mat Yes, so that eliminates a `QPaintDevice` pixel metric discrepancy. Good question.

Comment: @Mat Ignore that last comment, I was doing it wrong...  Adding the `QGraphicsView` for the `QPaintDevice` arg in the `QFontMetrics` constructor corrected the issue.  Presumably there was some transformation going on in the view that was not factored in the metric calculations.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `QGraphicsView` for the `QPaintDevice` arg in the `QFontMetrics` constructor corrected the issue. Presumably there was some transformation going on in the view that was not factored in the metric calculations.